# Jquery Find element with specific data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

What function can I use to select child div of class="rate_stars".

I have a variable range from 1 - 5 and I want to select child div with that specific data-rating.

I have tried

```
 $('rate_widget').find().attr('data-rating', info).prevAll().andSelf().addClass('ratings_vote');
```

But it did't work.

```
<div id="r1" class="rate_stars"
                             data-post-id="<?php echo $post_id ?>"
                             data-user-id="<?php echo $user_id;  ?>"
                             data-nonce="<?php echo $nonce ?>"
                            >
    <div data-rating="1" class="ratings_stars"></div>
    <div data-rating="2" class="ratings_stars"></div>
    <div data-rating="3" class="ratings_stars"></div>
    <div data-rating="4" class="ratings_stars"></div>
    <div data-rating="5" class="ratings_stars"></div>
    <div class="total_votes">vote data</div>
</div>
```

Comment: [jQuery attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the attribute selector found in jQuery:

```
$('#r1').find('[data-rating="' + info + '"]')
```

**Reference:** [List of All jQuery Attribute Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/)

Comment: I am trying to add class to all its siblings but it doesn't work if i place the code in script.js but if i write it insdie console than it works perfectly.

Comment: $('.rate_widget').find('[data-rating="' + INFO + '"]').prevAll().andSelf().addClass('ratings_vote');

Comment: @Epistemologist You probably want to open a new question for that issue. Are the elements added dynamically? If so, they may not be present when the script first runs. Also, `.andSelf()` is deprecated in 1.8. You should consider using the new function [`.addBack()`](http://api.jquery.com/addBack/) in it's place (requires jQuery 1.8+).

Comment: This solution did not work for me. Then I tried `$('div[data-rating="1"'])` worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick

```
var $div = $('.rate_stars div[data-rating="1"'])
```

Where `1` can be replaced by a dynamic expression if necessary

Answer (score 3):

Another way from my experience is to do a jquery each over the elements then check the data attribute, e.g.

```
$( ".ratings_stars" ).each(function( index ) {
    if($(this).data('rating') == 1){
         //Do Something
    }
});
```

Comment: This works but will add an excessive amount of overhead for this small of task. Also note that the class is `ratings_stars` (plural on _ratings_)...

Comment: Very true, I've learnt more from the other answers. Thanks for the heads up on the typo